# Articulated Kinematics

Tags: kinematics, path-planning, nav2

I'm currently engaged in developing the lattice generator for the state lattice planner in Nav2. The motivation is to integrate articulated vehicles, which are characterized by 4 state variables, as opposed to the 3 state variables found in Ackermann, differential, and omnidirectional vehicles. Given that Nav2 typically utilizes a reference link (usually the base_link) for navigation, it's important that the path information corresponds to the vehicle's front section i presume. However, in the current implementation of the lattice generator, trajectory generation involves a form of parameterization that effectively creates a path using a continuous arc function. For clarifications I've tried to draw how it works:

[image]

My initial approach involved parameterize based on the front section and then calculating the **steering angle (hinge/pivot)**. In this method, I assumed a constant vehicle velocity with no slip, and a constant angular velocity for the front section. This allowed for the calculation of the steering angle's velocity, which I then integrated numerically to determine the steering angle's position. Below is the formula employed for this process:

[image]

Here is a picture of the result:

[image]

The image illustrates the last pose of a generated primitive, along with its calculated footprint box. However, the angles shown in this pose indicate an incorrect steering angle. Theoretically, the rear angle should equal the sum of the steering and front angles, which is not the case here.

After reevaluating my approach, I'm now leaning towards the idea that the parameterization might be more effective if it's focused on the pivot. The attached diagram showcases this new perspective, which I am currently testing. This strategy presumes a direct correlation between the steering angle and the positions of the front and rear sections, a shift from my original approach. Additionally, the poses of the front and rear sections can be conceptualized using a right triangle, where the hypotenuse represents the distance from the pivot point to the drive axle. This allows for a transformation of the front and rear poses relative to the pivot.

[image]

Overall, my question is whether the parameterization should focus on the pivot or the front section of the vehicle?